# Software for text search in files

Tags: software-recommendation, search

I am looking for a software that will search text in files from a folder similar to [XYplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/free.php).

Is there something similar?

Comment: Does it have to be a GUI tool?

Comment: @Octavian yes it has but even there is not, it will work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for strings inside files in a folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198110/how-to-search-for-strings-inside-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a very nice one that shipped with Ubuntu out of the box until 16.04. For modern releases, read the update below!

1. Open the Dash (<kbd>Super</kbd> key or the Ubuntu button) and begin typing until you find `Search for Files`

   [image]
2. The above is for Unity, the default Desktop Environment in Ubuntu. In menu-driven environments, go to `Applications` -> `Accessories` -> `Search for Files`

   [image]
3. Expand the `Select more options` section and enter the text to search for in the `Contains the text:` input field.

   [image]

Features:

- 100% GUI
- You can search for file names or content
- It does look in sub-folders.

Given your scenario (no terminal commands, simple to use interface) I think theres no better option.

PS: on the `Contains the text:` input field the '.' character is a wildcard. To escape it you have to use '[]'. E.g.: type `Contains the text: [.]myFunction` to search for .myFunction

---

**UPDATE**: Gnome Search Tool was unfortunately [removed from Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/gnome-search-tool) on early 2018. For Ubuntu 18.04 onwards there's `mate-search-tool`, from the `mate-utils` package, that looks and behave exactly like the defunct Gnome tool:

```
sudo apt install mate-utils
mate-search-tool
```

However, its associated `.desktop` launcher does not show by default in Gnome/Unity menu, but a simple edit can workaround that:

```
sed '/^OnlyShowIn/s/^/#/' /usr/share/applications/mate-search-tool.desktop \
> "$HOME"/.local/share/applications/mate-search-tool.desktop
```

Comment: yup, I didn't see i could add details

Comment: yes, you can... just click on "select more options" and you can have not only "Contains the Text" but also tons of other search options (date, user, file sizer, even regex expressions). I also missed this little beast for a long time... i wish it was integrated into Nautilus (kinda like F3 in Windows Explorer)

Comment: this is the same as i advised earlier `gnome-search-tool`

Comment: @Octavian: Thanks for providing the screenshots!

Comment: @Mikl: its the same result, the difference lies in approach on how to invoke it: your initial solution was focused on command-line invocation (or ALT+F2) and only briefly mentioned it could also be found on menu. Didnt say *where*, or what the program name was in the menu. Only after i post my answer you edited yours to provide the menu path and name. For newcomers, a Menu-oriented approach is always better than CLI invocation. ALT+F2 should only be used when the software is not avaliable in menu.

Comment: I'm not sure this tool still exists in this form after the Unity button. The answer by @wizztjh works though.

Comment: could someone help to find out where is this tool please? for Ubuntu 20.04. I searched this tool, it's not there anymore. How to get it back?

Comment: @Franva: it was removed from Ubuntu since 18.04. You could use the similar `mate-search-tool`: `sudo apt install mate-utils`

Comment: @MestreLion thanks for letting know. I went with SearchMonkey and it looks good as well :) have you tried to compare these 2?

Comment: @Franva, nope, never used SearchMonkey. Gnome/Mate Search Tool is fine for me as a simple find GUI, for anything more complex I prefer using `grep` and `find` directly on terminal

Comment: @Franva: Also, I usually tend to avoid software that's not in the repositories. SearchMonkey in particular does not even have a .DEB installer yet. It seems the project was inactive for *10 years* , still uses GTK2, and was revived in 2018 (possibly due to Gnome Search Tools being deleted from Ubuntu). Hopefully they'll migrate away from SourceForge to a proper GitHub hosting, and re-active their currently suspended website. They have a lot of catching up to fill this 10-year gap of inactivity.

Comment: @MestreLion good point. thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

use

```
 grep -nr <your text> .
```

put the text that you want to find inside the <your text>

Comment: does it look in sub folders

Comment: `experimentx@workmateX:/var/www/testingzedn$  grep -nr application.ini` is taking forever ... am i incorrect

Comment: need the dot . , it will look into the folder with the -r

Comment: grep -nr application.ini     .

Answer (score 10):

you can use

```
find . -name '*.*' -exec grep -Hn 'text to find' '{}' \;
```

-name '*.*' or '*.txt' (use file mask here)
'text to find' (place text you want to find here)

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Hn 'text to find' '{}' \;
```

if you want to search all files

Comment: For all files, do not use `-name '*.*'` as files do not always have an extension. Use `-type f` instead (for searching in all files). Replace `{}` by `"{}"`, otherwise file names with whitespace in it do not get searched correctly.

Comment: @Lekensteyn i have edited my post.  but i made some test with files with whitespaces in names and no error while using {} witout quotes.

Comment: just tested it too and you are right, whitespace is not a problem. In some shells, the quotes might still be necessary to prevent shell expansion. From `man find`: "Both of these con‐
              structions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell."

Answer (score 10):

I am a fan of [searchmonkey](http://searchmonkey.embeddediq.com/index.php) (GPL, free, cross-platform, pretty light on resources and very fast).

[image]

Comment: Looks good. Will give it a try on other platforms since the top voted answer fits my bill on Ubuntu.

Comment: Seems it does not work on 64 bit operating systems (I faced the problem on win 7 64 bit). This is deal breaker for me as I use 64 bit OSes everywhere. Looked promising though.

Comment: @AmolGawai working perfectly at ubuntu 64bit here...

Answer (score 9):

GUI (Graphical) tool:

```
gnome-search-tool
```

you can find it in Ubuntu main menu

```
Menu -> Accessories -> Search for Files
```

or run it using hot key ALT+F2

Comment: Just an update for newer Ubuntu versions: on Unity interface (Ubuntu 12 or superior), click on Dash Home (the first icon on toolbar), type "search" and select "Search Files" application.

Answer (score 4):

[Regexxer](http://regexxer.sourceforge.net/) will let you search text in files. Not sure what you mean by "in folders".

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 3):

Graphical search:

in Kubuntu open Dolphin, then Edit->Find (Ctrl+F)

change from filename to Content and adjust from where to look for.

Answer (score 2):

Recoll does indexing and you can do full text searches of documents and email.

Comment: Looking into 50.000 folders is a pain :D if you don't index the data, so if you cannot buy a SSD disk, install any indexing tool before you waste time looking for files. Do the job once. Even if is not an answer to current question is a good point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I compared three of the suggestions in here with 64 bit 16.04 Kubuntu:

1. Searchmonkey works with 64-bit Ubuntu nowadays. It is similar to
   regexxer. It appeared fast, but naturally it is much slower than
   index based search.
2. Search for Files and Alt-F2 don't work with
   the KDE Ubuntu version.
3. My recommendation is Recoll and I have added some installation
   instructions for it. For me, the default installation supported PDF (test this!), DOCX, TAR, ZIP etc.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
   sudo apt-get install recoll antiword
   recoll
   ```
4. First line is probably not required: it adds partner installation repository.
5. Antiword is optional. It is needed to support older .doc files.
6. Enable following symbolic links and the root directory from Recoll Preferencies if necessary.
7. Create cron job for Recoll indexing using the GUI or make it to start on every login.
8. Change the Recoll setting in preferences from English to All languages if appropriate for you.
9. Start the indexing, at least for me it was surprisingly fast and didn't use all resources so I was able to continue using the laptop.
10. I have found one bug from Recoll so far: if you search for file name with "PST", it doesn't find it even though it is in uppercase. "pst" works and it finds both uppercase and lowercase names.
11. See more about recoll from https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/features.html

If you wish to add support for Outlook PST files, then you need to execute the following as well.

```
    sudo apt-get install readpst
    mkdir ~/PST
    find -L ~ -name "*.pst" -print | awk "{ printf \"%s%s %s%s%s %s\\n\", \"mkdir ~/PST/\", \$1, \"; readpst -o ~/PST/\", \$1, \" -D -j 4 -r -tea -u -w\", \$1 }" > /tmp/myPstFiles
    cat /tmp/myPstFiles
    chmod 755 /tmp/myPstFiles
    /tmp/myPstFiles
```

1. Change root directory from ~ to / if necessary in the find command.
2. My find script has a bug in it: it creates too long directory structure now. But it was easier for me to modify the temp file manually than to find a fix to this. Main target was that this will work for several PST files and it does that.
3. See more about Readpst from  http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/rn01re01.html and https://blog.robseder.com/2015/08/29/working-with-a-pst-file-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

I'm really want to introduce one tool which is based on ncurses library to provide the text-based user interface. The tool called NCGREP(grep based on ncurses) is mainly for search text in the specific folder. Hope this is what you want.
This source of the tool has been hosted on github.com, see more at https://github.com/ncgrep/ncgrep

[image]
<sup>Click image to see demo animation</sup>