# How to search for a string inside of multiple files (in nested folder structure)?

Tags: files, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for text search in files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29483/software-for-text-search-in-files)

I have a python project with nested folder structure

```
src/
  folder_1
  folder_2
    subfolder_1
    subfolder_2
  folder_3
    subfolder_1
      subsubfolder_1
    subfolder_2
  etc.
```

I am looking for a piece of code and the project is too big to go through every file manually.

**Is there a way to search for a string "mystring" inside all the files located in src or any subfolder of src?**

Comment: Possible dublicate - [Software for text search in files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29483/software-for-text-search-in-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`grep -R src/*`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/grep)