# How to search for strings inside files in a folder?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any utility to make searches for a string inside ASCII files to avoid command line searches?

How to make a command line search, for example for the string "test" inside all files in the directory `/var/x/`?

Comment: You really mean _without_ using command line ? Because the best tool for that remains grep...

Comment: On CLI [The Silver Searcher](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) probably does a better job.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use searchmonkey. The tool is available in the repositories, so you can simply

```
sudo apt-get install searchmonkey
```

On the other hand, command line search with grep is really intended for that...

Here is a screenshot from searchmonkey

[image]

Comment: crashed due to too much load :(

Comment: i have had issues with searchmonkey.  It is not trustworthy in the sense that it lets slips lots of occurrences

Comment: how do I run "searchmonkey" from the GUI? after installed using the command line, I'd rather not use the command line

Answer (score 166):

I assume that your first question is about a GUI alternative to the `grep` command. I can't help you with that, I always find the command line very effective.

As for the command line, try

```
grep "test" /var/x/*
```

If you want to search recursively (i.e. not only in `/var/x/`, but also in subdirectories thereof), do

```
grep -R "test" /var/x/
```

To avoid grepping the files which grep thinks to be binary, use the `-I` option:

```
grep -I "test" /var/x/
```

If grep thinks a file is binary (based on first few bytes of the file), it will assume it does not match instead of going through the whole file.

Comment: Will it work if the folder contain some non-ascii files?

Comment: Well, grep will also try search for the string in a binary file, and report it if it matches: `Binary file file.jpg matches`

Comment: but it may take a long time which is unnecessary

Comment: However, formally there is no difference between binary and ASCII files on a POSIX system. Therefore, I don't see why grepping "binary" files should take more time than equally large text files. Unless you completely want to avoid grepping binary files (yes, it can be useful).

Comment: @January When a binary file is read as text, it often has extremely long "lines" (because a character or character sequence that would be interpreted to designate the end of a line may not appear for a long time, or ever). Depending on the way a text search utility is implemented, this could cause performance problems if each "line" is read fully into memory and then checked to see if it matches the search string (which is a reasonable way for `grep` to be coded, though I don't know if Ubuntu's `grep` is written that way).

Comment: Well, it all depends on the files you have. I've got plenty of ascii files with extremely long lines. Also, grep (Ubuntu uses the standard GNU grep) has a bit more complex algorithm (you can see the sources with `apt-get source grep`), and, in short, it reads long lines in chunks.

Comment: "grep -i" for case insensitive search

Comment: There should be a `*` after the final slash in the path or grep does not appear to do any work in 14.04

Comment: @January Is there any option for `grep` to print the actual lines matching the string? Currently I only get `Binary file myFile.pdf matches`. Thank you.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 21):

You can use **regexxer** it is a great GUI search/replace tool for regular expressions.

you can download by:

```
sudo apt-get install regexxer
```

[image]

Comment: it is super fast, but the issues i have with this application are: 1. it does not have a readonly mode, so I don't accidentally replace or delete anything 2. it shows the text, but it will not move to the specific line that the pattern has matched. (I scrolled around 2000 lines of code to find what I was after after changing the color to bright red!)

Answer (score 8):

Try Recoll, best GUI one I ever used. To install recoll in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install recoll
```

It needs some time to index the files first (you can define blacklist path or extensions or mime).

Comment: I can confirm that Recoll is completely another world with respect to `gnome-search-tool` or `search-monkey`. It uses Xapian, so it's able to inspect and index word documents (both .doc and .docx), pdf files, mail folders, etc.

Comment: Uh, it's available through deb packaging (`sudo apt install recoll`) and it does its job where even grep fails, e.g. with .docx documents that are compressed with pkzip compression.

Comment: note that `recoll` requires building index first.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `grep` command from terminal:

`grep -r string *`

This command will find all occurrences of "string" in all the files under the current directory (or subdrectories).

For hidden files, you can use:

`grep -r string ..`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately grep does a very poor job of searching inside Word (.doc) files, but you can pipe catdoc output into grep. I'm no programmer but this little script works well for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
echo -e "\n
Welcome to scandocs. This will search .doc (NOT .docx) files in this directory for a given string. \n
Type in the text string you want to find... \n"
read response
find . -name "*.doc" | 
while read i; do catdoc "$i" | 
grep -iH --label="$i" "$response"; done
```

All improvements and suggestions welcome!

Comment: This question was about graphical applications and plain text files. I'm not sure what `grep` and `.doc` have to do with the question.

Comment: Seems OK, see January's detailed answer about `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

I've just released a simple tool to do the job. Thought mainly for software developer, it has the (unique?) characteristic of openning several files in the same window. It presents the results in the browser using Ace editor (recomended!) or html textarea. It is a java based tool so it runs in windows as well as in linux.

check it out!

https://sourceforge.net/projects/queacetu.gastona.p/

Answer (score 1):

per https://askubuntu.com/a/1141367/47073

You can use `mate-search-tool`, which is the same thing as `gnome-search-tool` that was removed. I had problems with searchmonkey, it was missing some results and was slow, do not recommend.

To install `mate-search-tool`:

```
sudo apt install mate-utils
mate-search-tool
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Sublime Text** `Find in Files` option from `Find` menu to search for strings inside files from a folder.

## To Install Sublime Text 3

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

You can also follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3) question for other possible ways of installing **Sublime** on **Ubuntu**.

To search in all files for a string from a folder in **Sublime Text** you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519040/search-in-all-files-in-a-project-in-sublime-text-3) question for more clear answers.