# Enable Num Lock At Login Screen For Lubuntu

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

I have tried a few solutions to enable this option, but nothing is working.  I am running Lubuntu 18.04 LTS

And what I have tried is 
1)

> sudo pcmanfm
>     /etc/xdg/lubuntu/lxdm/lxdm.conf
>     numlock=1

And 
 2)

```
sudo su -
apt-get install numlockx
echo "/usr/bin/numlockx on" >> /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

And 
 Lastly 3) install numlockx via synaptic

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on 
sudo reboot
```

However, after reboot the num lock key is still not on.

Comment: I think this option is natively controlled by BIOS/UEFI settings

Comment: `50-greeter-wrapper.conf` is the wrong file to edit on step 3

Comment: I don't know the name of the file that you're gonna need because it's different for each distro. But I'd suggest installing ubuntu 14.04 on a vm and then take a look at the file `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf` and then try to find this file on your own machine somehow. It will have a different name on your distro but the contents will be almost the same.

Comment: At last, if you found the file, please write an answer here so other Lubuntu users can find the file easily. This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/198110/how-to-search-for-strings-inside-files-in-a-folder

Answer (score 1):

This is now easily available in Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS: Start Menu > Preferences > LXQt settings > Keyboard and Mouse > Keyboard. Then check the box "Turn on NumLock after login".

Answer (score 1):

For Lubuntu 2020.04 : go to Keyboard and Mouse Settings by: Start >> Preferences >> LXQt settings >> Keyboard and Mouse
Than select Keyboard and click last option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 16.04, so I don't know if this will work on 18.04.

I added numlockx to Default Applications in LXSession - Get to it via Menu > Preferences.
When it comes up, select "Autostart" in the left panel.
Then type "numlockx" into the empty box next to the [+Add] button, then click that +Add button.  You'll see it show up in the list just above that.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

for me the 3 solution but in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf` :

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=Lubuntu
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

[edit]

See in [LightDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) :

```
System provided configuration is stored in 
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf and is not user editable. 
System administrators can override this configuration in 
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf and /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf. 
Files are read in the above order and combined together to make the 
LightDM configuration.

For example, if you want to override the system configured default 
session (provided in /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf) 
you should make a file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf
```

[/edit]

enjoy