# How do I speed up searches in files?

Tags: search

I know that on windows you can index your files to find things faster. Is there something like this for Ubuntu because when I search for something like /usr under files it says searching and it takes really long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes

```
sudo updatedb
```

then

```
locate foo
```

see http://www.linfo.org/locate.html

You can also use find

```
find /usr -name foo
```

see http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm

For a graphical tool see [Software for text search in files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29483/software-for-text-search-in-files)